# Custom shape in Tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-shape, tikz-node

is it possible to create a costum shape with tikz node like in figure without using pgf?

[image]

It is like this (but now I have to include the third block):

[image]

Comment: Why do you need a node of that shape? If you give more details on the use case, maybe someone comes up with an alternative solution.

Comment: Like this?: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239976/1952

Comment: I have to draw a sort of big block that contains these little 3 blocks

Comment: But does it have to be *node*, or can you just draw the outline with `\draw`? And please show us the code you have so far, if you want advice on improving it.